# Center a Large Div on All Screens But Allow Scrolling?

Tags: css, scroll, margin, center

I am trying to figure out how to make a large div centered on all screens, but also be scrollable for smaller screens that otherwise couldn't see all of the div.

For example, let's say the div has the size of 1200px x 600px. Using the following will center the div, but not allow scrolling on smaller screen sizes:
`position: fixed; left: 0px; right: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; margin: auto;`

My goal is to find a way to allow these smaller computer screens to see the entirety of the large div (via scrolling) but still have the div be centered on screens of all sizes.

Is this possible? In addition, is there a non-javascript solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it will solve your problem.

```css
.main-wrapper {
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
          justify-content: center;
          min-height: 100vh;
          height: auto;
          padding: 20px;
          background: red;
      }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="main-wrapper">
    <div class="internal-content">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae, perspiciatis. Assumenda cupiditate culpa obcaecati molestias architecto facilis! Ratione laboriosam reprehenderit asperiores et ipsum est, quisquam modi beatae odio enim nostrum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet libero nam nulla assumenda optio iure adipisci, exercitationem deserunt a. Similique illum cumque eveniet quam enim in provident expedita culpa officia! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing, elit. Cupiditate ipsam et, nostrum. Dolorum autem qui voluptas doloribus voluptatibus est laboriosam perferendis blanditiis et quaerat iusto, vitae unde itaque dolore nulla.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Rem recusandae, repellat velit rerum. Repellendus harum, sequi architecto deleniti tenetur cumque, ducimus itaque, nam officia vero minima quos, debitis quis sunt. Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Architecto, quaerat, illum. Aperiam, repellendus sit atque architecto cupiditate. Quis consequuntur, iure nihil doloremque, aut distinctio quibusdam rem, mollitia incidunt, voluptate quasi?
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```